# Copy One textbox value to another textbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to copy one textbox value to another using onblur event. I'm newbie in jQuery. Please suggest the write way to do this task.

JavaScript code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

});

function myFunction(one, two) {
    $('#<%= txtOne.ClientID %>').val($('#<%= txtSecond.ClientID %>').val());
}

</script>
```

HTML markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" onblur="myFunction('<%= txtOne.ClientID %>','<%= txtSecond.ClientID %>');"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSecond" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: but what can i do if we have more than two text boxes- BCartolo

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
function myFunction(one, two) {
    $("#"+one).val($("#"+two).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use plain old javascript?

```
   document.getElementById("<%= txtOne.ClientID %>").value = document.getElementById("<%= txtSecond.ClientID %>").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" onblur="myFunction('txtOne','txtSecond');"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then use what Callebe suggested

```
function myFunction(one, two) {
    $("#"+one).val($("#"+two).val());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function sync()
{
  var t1 = document.getElementById('txtOne');
  var t2 = document.getElementById('txtSecond');
  t1.value = t2.value;
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="n1" id="txtOne" onkeyup="sync()">
<input type="text" name="n2" id="txtSecond"/>
```